# Select dataframe using correlated columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe in which I need to select only rows where B.startswith(A) - rows #0 and #3. Sure it can be done with apply method but I wonder there is a more elegant way

| # | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | abc |
| 1 | b | abc |
| 2 | c | abc |
| 3 | x | xyz |
| 4 | y | xyz |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all elements in A are single characters, you can take the first element of B and compare with A:

```
df[df['B'].str[0].eq(df['A'])]
```

output:

```
   #  A    B
0  0  a  abc
3  3  x  xyz
```

If you don't know in advance the length of the strings in A, you can use `apply`:

```
df[df.apply(lambda r: r['B'].startswith(r['A']), axis=1)]
```

Comment: `.eq(…)` is actually the same as `==`, you could do `df[df['B'].str[0] == df['A']]` ;)